# Azure Search : Running Indexer for .vtt

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-media-services, indexer, vtt

I am using Azure Search for searching through contents of files stored in the blob.
When I include .vtt file, generated by Azure Media Services V3 indexer, in my blob storage and run the Indexer, it fails.
Is it because of some specific content of the file? Why does the indexer fail to index .vtt file?

Has anyone tried doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The following link contains the list of supported document formats for the blob indexer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Notice that currently the blob indexer does not have built-in support for .vtt files.

Thanks,
Luis Cabrera
Principal Program Manager, Azure Search

Comment: what's so special about .vtt files? Looks like a simple text file to me..

Comment: VTT files are a combination of json and Text. (but not pure JSON)